# Components parameters empty in Joomla 3.2

Tags: parameters, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla1.6

I'm porting a **Joomla 1.6** component to **3.2**. In **1.6** I was able to read the components parameters defined via **config.xml** in a view of the component. In **3.2** the parameters are empty since the value *$imagepath* is always set to *'impossibru!'*.

**This is the code I use for my view:**

```
<?php

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view' );

class BooomViewGame extends JViewLegacy
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        var_dump(JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_booom')); //debug

        $params =& JComponentHelper::getParams('com_booom');
        var_dump($params);  //debug

        // Read the path parameter.
        $imagepath = $params->get('imagepath', 'impossibru!');

        // Make the path available on the template.
        $this->assignRef('imagepath', $imagepath);

        [some other stuff]
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the code of my config.xml defining the components parameters:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <fieldset name="component">
        <field name="imagepath" type="text" default="images" label="Image path" description="Path to images of the game."/>
    </fieldset>
</config>
```

**The output of the var_dump()s is as follows:**

```
object(stdClass)#119 (4) { ["id"]=> string(5) "10004" ["option"]=> string(9) "com_booom" ["params"]=> object(JRegistry)#111 (1) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#118 (0) { } } ["enabled"]=> string(1) "1" }

object(JRegistry)#111 (1) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#118 (0) { } }
```

As you can see the *JParameter* object does not contain any values. I can see and set the parameter within the configuration part of the joomla backend, though! Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters aren't available in the views until you go to the configuration of the component in Joomla and click on the save button.

Comment: can you describe how can I change the configuration of the component ?